# Apache / Drupal configuration on my AWS instance

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, drupal, virtualization

I am a newbie and need some help although I tried going through the other posts. I have successfully installed my drupal site in /var/www/mywebsite folder.

Now I went to the place from where I bought my domain (mywebsite.com) and configured an A record to point to the Elastic IP Address allocated by Amazone to this instance. Everything is fine a nice here. When I browse for mywebsite.com it correctly takes me to the default page in /var/www

But obviously I need to point that website to /var/www/mywebsite. When I enter the link mywebsite.com/mywebsite ... it goes to the right page and everything seems to work fine.

Now what I want to do is point mywebsite.com and www.mywebsite.com to the /var/www/mywebsite folder

And it would be great if I could have another site called yourwebsite.com and I configure it to the same IP but the redirection for yourwebsite.com and www.yourwebsite.com to /var/www/yourwebsite

Please help! I understand that the issue has something to with VirtualHosts and mod_rewrite .. but sorry ... I'm a bit stuck and rather new! HELP! :(

Comment: Sorry .. I think I figured out atleast partially which is good enough for a start.

I will appreciate if anyone could warn me of things I may be missing (if any).I added the below to the httpd.conf file and atleast one site is up and running!

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAdmin  admin@mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/mywebsite/>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    order allow,deny

    allow from all

</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

What you suggested is exactly right. The httpd.conf is not the best place to put this, you should go to:

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

in there, copy 000-default to www.mysite.com

edit it, e.g.

vi www.mysite.com

Adjust the details as you suggested in your question (Insert)

Save (Escape, :w, enter)

Quit vi (Escape, :q,enter)

Finally,
type:

a2ensite www.mysite.com

apache2ctl restart

and you should have it.